# Apex Server-Side Controller Overview (If a method returns an object, instance methods...)

Tags: lightning-aura-components

this is my first question here.

I going through the Salesforce documentation for Aura Components and in the section of apex-side controllers there is a line that I don't understand, so I wonder if anyone can help me explaining me this.

This is the line

[image]

and this is the link of the documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex.htm

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are referring to the Apex [Access Modifiers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm); you cannot use a private method for a getter. This means the following examples are invalid code:

```
public class ResultValue {
    // Compiles, but will not be sent to client
    @AuraEnabled public String message { private get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class ResultValue {
    // Will not compile
    @AuraEnabled private String message { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class ResultValue {
    // Will not compile
    @AuraEnabled String message { get; set; } // Omitted access is same as private
}
```

---

```
public class ResultValue {
    // Note: getValue methods will remove get and lowercase the first letter
    // This property would be accessed as result.getReturnValue().message
    // Will not compile
    @AuraEnabled private String getMessage() {
        return 'Some Message';
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ResultValue {
    // Will not compile
    @AuraEnabled String getMessage() { // Omitted is same as private
        return 'Some Message';
    }
}
```

Comment: got it, thank you very much